# Is the remainder of first-order Taylor expansion still continuously differentiable?

Tags: derivatives, continuity, taylor-expansion

Let $f: {\mathbb R}^n \to {\mathbb R}^n$ be a continuously differentiable function. Then, we can rewrite its first-order Taylor expansion at $x \in {\mathbb R}^n$ for $h \in {\mathbb R}^n$ that
\begin{align}
f(x+h) = f(x) + f'(x) h + r(h),
\end{align}
where $f'(x) \in {\mathbb R}^{n\times n}$. Since $f$ is differentiable, we have
\begin{align}
r'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {r(h)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac {f(x+h) - f(x) - f'(x) h}{h} = 0.
\end{align}

Now, the question is coming. Is r(h) continuously differentiable for $h$?

From my point of view, r(h) is continuously differentiable for $h$, and the reason is given as follows:

I rewrite the first equation as
\begin{align}
r(h) = f(x+h) - f(x) - f'(x) h.
\end{align}

For any fixed $x \in {\mathbb R}^n$, $f(x+h)$ is continuously differentiable w.r.t. $h$, so is $f'(x) h$. Thus, in my opinion, $r(h)$ is continuously differentiable with $r'(0) = 0$.

However, I am not sure this reason is correct...

Comment: yes, it's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. $r(h) = f(x+h) - f(x) -f'(x)h$ and all terms on the right hand side are continuously differentiable, then so is the left hand side.